# Manipulating isosceles triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
    \usepgflibrary{decorations.shapes}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes, shapes, fit, arrows, positioning, trees, mindmap, calc}
    \tikzset{
        rubber/.style={
            draw=red!50,
            shape border rotate=-90,
            isosceles triangle,
            fill=red!50,
            minimum height=1.5cm,
            minimum width =0.05cm,
        }
    }
    \tikzset{
        ducky/.style={
            draw=red!50,
            shape border rotate=90,
            isosceles triangle,
            fill=red!50,
            minimum height=1.5cm,
            minimum width =0.05cm,
        }
        }
        \begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[rubber] at (0,0) {};
    \node[ducky] at (0,0.5) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> Is there any way to make the triangles taller and skinnier?

Comment: Don't use the `minimum width` (or use a smaller value) and use the option `isosceles triangle stretches`. You can also specify the `isosceles triangle apex angle` directly. I advise you to read pages 428f of the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). (You may also search for `isosceles triangle` in the PDF.)

Comment: In addition, there's no need to load the `pgf` package since TikZ already loads it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need two keys:

- The `isosceles triangle stretches` option ignores the `isosceles triangle apex angle` (default set to `30`) and makes it possible to use `minimum width` and `minimum height` to specify the exact dimensions of the `isosceles triangle` key.
- For very small values you also need to set the `inner sep` keys to `0pt` (default is `.3333em`).

I advise you to read pages 428f. of the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). (You may also search for isosceles triangle in the PDF.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
    rubberduck/.style={
        draw=red!50,
        shape=isosceles triangle,
        fill=red!50,
        minimum height=1.5cm,
        minimum width=0.5cm,
        shape border rotate=#1,
        isosceles triangle stretches,
        inner sep=0pt,
    },
    rubber/.style={rubberduck=+90},
    ducky/.style={rubberduck=-90}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rubber] at (0,0) {};
\node[ducky] at (1,1.5) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]